# Beginner Google Glass coder baby steps

Tags: ruby, pdf, google-glass

I am part of the glassexplorer program (circa ifihadglass). I am trying to develop some applications for glass but I don't know where to start.

I am trying to make a practice app that lets users search for data found  on medical device websites: 
http://www.bostonscientific.com/peripheral-interventions-eu/Products/View-Featured-Products/Balloon-Dilatation-Catheters/MustangBalloon-Dilatation-System.html (the table at the bottom of the page in gray, see the first line) screenshot with relevant data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/smcBh.jpg

With the practice app I want to say "what is the rated burst pressure of a 3 by 20 balloon"

and i want it to respond 24 ATM or 2431 kPa

What's the best way to tackle making this app, including code language etc?

Clarity:

I have zero programming experience but I am extremely computer literate.

Answer (score 0):

You have a **lot** of parts to your question, and you're somewhat vague about your skills and background, so it really isn't easy to give you a straightforward answer.

If you're a programmer - the Mirror API can handle just about any server-based programming language that you're used to. If you're familiar with Ruby - go with that. If you're familiar with something else, there are code samples (and libraries) available for Java, Python, Go, .NET, and PHP and further information for other languages if necessary. Find the language that works best for you to access the data.

Speaking of accessing the data, it isn't clear where your data comes from, so that is pretty difficult to advise you on. Although you called it a PDF, you pointed to an image file. It looks like it comes out of a spreadsheet or database. Trying to access a PDF or image will be very difficult, while getting it out of the database would be far easier using any of the languages. You should probably ask another SO question specifically focusing on this portion of the problem if you're uncertain how to approach it.

On the Glass side, you should probably become familiar with how most Glassware these days work. Most don't let you ask free-form questions from the "ok, glass" screen. Even Google makes you issue a command before doing a query! While you can leverage a menu item such as "post an update" to send the text of the query, you'll then need to handle the query text itself as part of your server.

You may want to update your question to address some of these issues - or break it up into smaller parts first, tackle those parts, and ask questions with specific problems as you encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what posted, I would add that you can get the data from the webpage by parsing it but then it will never be stable. The better option would be to contact the author of the page to get the data. This will make sure that in case of any changes on webpage, you still get the result.

I would suggest starting with Java since you are new to programming. It will give you the maximum support, as applications for Glass are majorly similar to android applications.

And other than that the Glass documentation is sufficient enough to give you an idea of the whole development perspective. https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/index

So in all learn java, specifically android development, read the documentation and you should be good to go.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the data"  from the author of the page

Comment: Since most websites are dynamic and store their data in databases, the best way is to get the database from the website. If the website has an API, you can use it.